# Some font-awesome not showing on Prestashop 1.6

Tags: css, font-awesome, prestashop-1.6

I'm new using Prestashop 1.6. I'm facing with this issue.

I can't see some font-awesome icons, [as you can see on attach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OTf5.jpg), (probably due to modules activated and then disactivated).

I think issue is on global.css:

```
div.star:after{

content: "f005"

}
```

when i change this by chrome console in:

```
div.star:after{

content: "\f005"

}
```

font-awesome icon works perfectly, so I'm pretty sure problem is "\" missing on global.css.

I tried to change this directly on file global.css, but I see, by chrome console,  css version without "\" is still loading.

Someone could help me finding solution?

Comment: Issue solved. I failed to modify the right css elements in global.css.